# Authentication local user account with azure active directory

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use both local user account and azure active directory in my asp.net core 2.0 application.

They both work good individually(with only activating one of them), but when I activate both of them, azure active directory authentication is not working.

Failed Case:
After returning back to my web app from authentication on azure website, my web app `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `False`.

Steps:

1. Forward client to azure authentication website with following code:

   `public IActionResult LoginWithOpenId(string returnUrl)
   {
   return Challenge("myAzureAD");
   }`
2. Login on azure website.
3. Return back to callback path.
4. Callback set the required cookies.
5. `IsAuthenticated`still False.

Here is the code:

Startup.cs

```
        services
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("testdb");
            });

        services
            .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDataContext>();

        services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("myAzureAD", options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "xxx";
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx";
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            })
            .AddCookie();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

AccountController

```
    public IActionResult LoginWithOpenId(string returnUrl)
    {
/*This is always false, 
if I remove AddIdentity from StartUp class to disable local authentication,
this line is working*/
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("private", "home");
        }
        else
        {
            return Challenge("myAzureAD");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you mention client secret for openIdConnect?

Comment: Hi t-prisar, I don't set client secret anywhere on app, openIdConnect is working without client secret(if I remove local user authentication code), so I think problem related with another configuration.

Comment: I suspect that authentication middleware doesn't read the Identity.External cookie(which is set by '/signin-oidc' response) from request so that it doesn't set the current user as authenticated, not sure for this.